# How to tell parent component that I need updated props?

Tags: reactjs

I have a component which is a form that receives props.

When I save the form I want to tell the parent component to send me updated props.

How can I do that?

Comment: Please share some code so we can help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably looking for a pattern similar to this:

```
function ChildComponent(props) {
  const [text, setText] = useState(props.text)

  const handleClick = () => {
    const newText = 'New Value'
    setText(newText);
    // this is needed to stop errors if the prop wasn't set.
    props.onTextUpdated ? props.onTextUpdated(newText) : null;
  }

  return (
    <div>
      {text}
      <button onClick={handleClick}>Send Update</button>
    </div>
  )
}

function ParentComponent() {
  const [text, setText] = useState('this is some initial text');

  const handleUpdate = (newValue) => {
    alert('We could setText here too if we wanted!');
    alert(newValue)
  }

  return (
    <ChildComponent onTextUpdated={handleUpdate} text={text} />
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the documentation?

I think the [documentation](https://fr.reactjs.org/docs/forms.html) is clear on this. I'm not sure I understand you but I see that in the documentation,
we have a simple example of what to ask

```
class NameForm extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {value: ''};

    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange(event) {
    this.setState({value: event.target.value});
  }

  handleSubmit(event) {
    alert('Le nom a été soumis : ' + this.state.value);
    event.preventDefault();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
        <label>
          Nom :
          <input type="text" value={this.state.value} onChange={this.handleChange} />
        </label>
        <input type="submit" value="Envoyer" />
      </form>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to pass to the child component some callback that he can call when needed.

for example

```js
const ChildComponent = ({callBack, data}) => {

return <>
  <h1>{data}</h1>
  <button onClick={callBack}>Click me</button>
</>

}


const ParentComponent = props => {
  
  const [number, setNumber] = useState(0)

  return <ChildComponent data={number} callBack={() => {setNumber(n => n + 1)}}
}
```